# Flush valve piping, ok to go straight up instead of into wall?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, valve

I am thinking of replacing my upstairs toilet tanks with commercial-style flush valves. Normally the supply pipe to the valve goes into the wall and then upwards through the wall. In my situation it will be far easier to have the supply pipe simply go straight up into the ceiling, instead of having it go into the wall first. Is there any problem with piping it this way?

Comment: The main problem I see is that potential buyers, when the time comes, may be put off by it. Other than that .. _up_ in an upstairs bathroom? i guess it depends how water's being distributed in your place, but I'm a trifle surprised.

Comment: @keshlam The water reservoir is in the attic. It has to be above the toilet to provide a gravity flush.

Comment: Oh, I see. Like the old British system minus the pull-chain. I presume that where you live attics never freeze.

Comment: @keshlam All commercial flushing systems use gravity feed systems. If you don't have expertise in the technology/question you should not be involving yourself in the question.

Comment: Be sure that your water pressure and flow will be high enough to support a commercial flush toilet; the ones I've seen need more pressure/flow than most home water pipes could supply.

Comment: Tyler, I'm asking because I want to understand and learn. That's why I commented rather than answering.  I believe that's within SE's mission.

Comment: "all commercial flushing systems use gravity feed systems" is an utterly untrue statement. Using the word "feed" would lead most to think of water supply. Is gravity part of how flushing works? Yes. Are all system supplies ("feed") gravity fed? No.

Comment: @TylerDurden - there are certainly many (most?) commercial flush valves that use water pressure rather than a gravity feed, if you're looking for information about a particular type of flush valve, it is customary to put that information into the question. I've never come across any above-ceiling reservoirs in any commercial building I've worked in.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find anything in the IBC that prohibits exposed supply pipes in bathrooms.  The only relevant sections I could locate were:

> **310.2 Location of fixtures and piping.** Piping, fixtures or equipment shall not be located in such a manner as to interfere with the normal
>   operation of windows, doors or other means of egress openings.

...and...

> **405.6 Plumbing in mental health centers.** In mental health centers, pipes or traps shall not be exposed, and fixtures shall be bolted
>   through walls.

Of course, your local code may be more or less stringent.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you could consider my house a mental health center. I guess I need to have the pipe in the wall.

Comment: I think that it "should" be in the wall for general cosmetic/resale reasons, but  I think if it was done in what my wife calls "Warehouse Chic" way, it could look really cool. Great question.